# Comparison function inside class [error 2878]: binary '<': no operator found which takes a left hand operand of type

Tags: c++, stl

Why I've getting that error? I saw a video running such code and has no error at all. I don't would like to define outside of class. What is wrong?

```
class Person
{
public:
    int age;
    string name;

    bool operator < (const Person& rhs) { return age < rhs.age; }
};

int main()
{
    std::set<Person> my;
    Person p{ 10, "Eduardo" };
    my.insert(p);
}
```

Comment: `bool operator < (const Person& rhs) const`

Answer (score 4):

You need to mark your `operator<` as being `const` so that it can be called on objects of type `const Person`:

```cpp
bool operator < (const Person& rhs) const { return age < rhs.age; }
                                    ^^^^^
```

The default *Compare* template parameter of `std::set<Person>` is `std::less<Person>`, which takes `const Person&` parameters in its `operator()`.

Your operator should be `const` anyway since it does not modify the members of the `Person` object it is called on.